# SQL Server : sum for every four years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table in SQL Server:

```
Table (Id, Year, Value)
```

and data like this:

```
Id | Year | Value
---+------+------
 1 | 1993 |  5
 2 | 1994 |  1
 3 | 1995 |  2
 4 | 1996 | 15
 5 | 1997 |  8
 6 | 1998 |  3
 7 | 1999 |  1
 8 | 2000 |  5
```

I need a sum for every four years, for example

```
Years     | SUM (Value)
----------+-------------
1993-1996 | 23
1997-2000 | 17
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want a specific start/end year for the binning? (Gordon's solution would still work fine, just needs a shift).

Answer (score 7):

You can use simple arithmetic:

```
select min(year), max(year), sum(value)
from t
group by (year - 1) / 4
order by min(year);
```

Notes:

- This puts the years into two columns.  You can concatenate them if you really want a string.
- This takes advantage of the fact that SQL Server does integer division.
- Note the `order by`, so the results are in your expected order.

Comment: select convert(varchar(4),min(year)) +'-'+convert(varchar(4),max(year)), sum(value) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0526/3/2)

You can play with the `group by` clause to get the specific grouping you want.

```
declare @StartYear int = 1993;
declare @YearsPerGroup int = 4;

select 
  case 
    when min([year]) = max([year]) then cast(min([year]) as varchar(10))
    else cast(min([year]) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(max([year]) as varchar(10))
  end as [Name],
  min([year]) as [Start Year], 
  max([year]) as [End Year],
  sum(Value) as [Sum (Value)]
from T
group by 
  ([year] - @StartYear) - ([year] - @StartYear) % @YearsPerGroup
```